# Change notification Icon on mouse hover

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change notification icon text on mouse hover using c#
e.g

```
  NotifyIcon notifyicon;
  notifyicon.Icon = (Icon)resManager.GetObject("test");
            notifyicon.Visible = true;
    if(a==b)
    {
     notifyicon.Text = "Both are equal";
    }
    else
    {
     notifyicon.Text = "Not equal";
    }
```

Is it possible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for the [ToolTip class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) on MSDN.  The "Examples" section should contain the information you need.